# What does たまる mean when it is connected to て?

Tags: subsidiary-verbs

I looked up the meaning of たまる and the meaning is accumulate. But sometimes I see たまる in the end of a sentence (e.g. あんな人のせいで　計画を潰してたまるもんか）

It seems like accumulate does not quite make sense in this sentence. Can anyone tell me what does that mean in this sentence.

If you can provide some more examples sentence it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a different verb: [堪る{たまる}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A0%AA%E3%82%8B-562944), used here in a set phrase たまるものか meaning roughly "is it at all possible?" or "there's no way it is so" - being more of a rhetorical question.

> そんなことがあってたまるか
>
> That can't be! No way!

The verb is also used in meaning "to bear", "to withstand" also to indicate something irresistible, like:

> ケーキが食べたくてたまらない
>
> I can't resist cakes.

Answer (score 7):

It actually has little to do with "to accumulate".  "To accumulate" is 「溜{た}まる」 or 「貯{た}まる」.

The verb in question is 「堪{たま}る」 ("to keep up with") and it is usually used in ***negative forms*** such as 「堪らない」.

「たまるもんか」 is negative in meaning, too.  It means "***That can't be!***", "***I'm not about to ~~!***", etc.  It is an expression of firm rejection.

> 「あんな人のせいで　計画{けいかく}を潰{つぶ}してたまるもんか。」

, therefore, means:

> "I'm not about to ruin my plans for such a man!"